# Constructing a graph with some balanced objectives in mind

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

**Background**

This question is my attempt to modify the well-known question of finding an algorithm to identify a spanning connected subgraph of a graph with the total minimum weights of the edges.

**Question**

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and let $E$ be a partition
of two sets $E=P\cup\bar{P}$, $P\cap\bar{P}=\emptyset$. Define the
function $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(e)=+1$ if $e\in P$ and
$f(e)=-1$ if $e\notin P$. Design an algorithm to identify the graph
$H=(V,F)$ such that $H$ is connected and $f(H)$ is closest to $0$.

Comment: $f(H)$ is not defined.  I think you meant instead $\sum_{e\in F} f(e)$.  Also, is the complement of $H$ required to be connected?

Comment: Yes you are correct, thank you for the correction. The complement of H may not be connected.